# Why is it true that $\sum_{\sigma \in S(n)} a_{\sigma(1)}a_{\sigma(2)} = 2(n-2)! \sum_{1\le i<j \le n}a_ja_k$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $S(n)$ be the set of permutations of $\{1,2,...,n\}$, and assume $a_i$ is a real number for $i=1,2,...,n$. Why is it true that $$\sum_{\sigma \in S(n)} a_{\sigma(1)}a_{\sigma(2)} = 2(n-2)! \sum_{1\le i<j \le n}a_ja_k?$$

Similarly, we also have $$\sum_{\sigma \in S(n)} a_{\sigma(1)} = (n-1)! \sum_{j=1}^na_j.$$

Comment: Take the number $a_{1}a_{2}$. How many times does this number occur? So you deduce that $a_{\sigma(1)}a_{\sigma(2)}=a_{1}a_{2}$ iff $\sigma=\text{id}$ along with a function which moves $1\to 2$ and $2\to 1$. So number of times $a_{1}a_{2}$ occurs is same as counting number of functions in $S(n)$ which are of the type $(1\,2)\cdot \tau$ or $\text{id} \cdot \tau$.

Comment: @crskhr Thank you. I used $S(4)$ to understand it.

Comment: Welcome! Glad to help :)